# A word to describe to deviate from original idea/concept/intention

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word to describe the outcome has deviated from original idea/concept/intention? The result is worse than expected.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence that demonstrates how the word would be used?

Answer (score 0):

"The outcome has strayed from our expectations" would usually (but not always, depending on context) mean that the outcome had deviated but not in a good way. You will find examples in the Oxford online dictionary https://www.lexico.com/definition/stray